# Image as texture in QT

Tags: c++, qt, textures

I'm having problems with a custom item in QT because i want to map a texture in a geometry using updatePaintNode, What should I do to load an image as a Texture in a sceneGraph in QT in the updatePaintNode method? please help me with an example, i've been searching for examples but all I found were very confusing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the texture, it is using [QQuickWindow::​createTextureFromImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#createTextureFromImage-2) function.

Another way is subclassing `QSGTexture` and implement your custom binding function. For detail see [QSGPlainTexture](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/20d160d0513a04be187ed851a25b029f47c27b27:src/quick/scenegraph/util/qsgtexture_p.h) source code.

Comment: Thank you!!! I could get my texture with QQuickWindow::​createTextureFromImage, I did not try with the other way you mentioned, cause I find it kind of weird, anyway Thak you.